# Origin of louse for the following: louse around--to idle and louse up--to ruin?

Tags: etymology, slang

I understand louse being singular for lice; however, I'm uncertain as to why louse around means to idle and louse up means to ruin. Any ideas?

Comment: Google shows just 23 instances of [*"just **louse** around"*](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?tab=ww&ei=BNqUU8ivKo3nPIXPgZAH&ved=0CBIQ1S4#q=%22just+louse+around%22&start=20), but it claims 4,600,000 instances of [*"just **lounge** around"*](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?tab=ww&ei=BNqUU8ivKo3nPIXPgZAH&ved=0CBIQ1S4#q=%22just+lounge+around%22). So I think it's General Reference that 23 people got it wrong.

Comment: @FumbleFingers certainly I have never heard of this expression but to say it is a misinterpretation or egghorn of *lounge around* didn't sound right either. Google books has 124 results for [louse around](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22louse+around%22&num=30&site=webhp&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ei=vUmVU_mBBMbBPP-ngNgP&ved=0CA4Q_AUoAQ&biw=1366&bih=653)

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I actually went through that list, which turns out to have 18 instances where the context clearly shows ***louse around*** being used as a "phrasal verb". At least half-a-dozen seemed to be "dictionary definitions", so the "use/mention" ratio is certainly quite unusual. It still seems quite credible to me that it only "exists" in the first place because of mis-repetition of ***lounge/loaf/loll/laze** around*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ***louse*** is a common derogatory term to describe a person who acts like a parasite, a pest, or someone extremely unpleasant.
Merriam-Webster offers this example: *[Her ex-husband is a real louse.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/louse)*

[D.C](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/louse) states: ***Slang*** *meaning "obnoxious person" is from 1630s*; ***to louse up*** *"ruin, botch" first attested 1934*.

The earliest instance of the phrase *louse around* I found in Google books was *[American Dialect Society](http://books.google.it/books?id=SbZZAAAAMAAJ&q=%22louse%20around%22&dq=%22louse%20around%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=w0mVU9KWFsnYPeTbgKgN&redir_esc=y)*, 1927

> v. phr. To loiter about aimlessly. Also, *Laze around*.

Which suggests that the term was not as derogatory as it is today. The better-known idiom, to *lounge around*,  is but another way of saying *to laze around*. The following excerpt confirms this meaning.

From 1931 *Shoe the Wild Mare* by Gene Fowler [image]

Nowadays however, the idiom expresses contempt and suggests a parasitic approach to life. [Wikitionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/louse_around) says

> 1. (UK) To slack off; be lazy; be a "parasite" to someone/something.

Answer (score 2):

The verb *louse* has two completely opposite meanings, to remove lice or to fill with lice (this apparent contradiction is not that rare, there are other verbs formed from nouns and meaning both adding or removing whatever the noun is).

Filling with lice generally makes something bad. Hence figuratively, any act that spoils or ruins is *lousing* or *lousing-up*.

"Louse around" sounds like an eggcorn for "lounge around", though since it isn't considered particularly productive, it could be as much a portmanteau of "lounge around" with *louse* in the sense just considered.

Comment: I checked online and lo and behold it is an idiomatic expression http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/louse_around

Comment: Google also proposes *lice around the house* before I finish typing, which suggests that the expression "louse around" is probably derived from that.

Answer (score 2):

> **Louse around**. To treat badly, as to cheat, persecute, or betray. "That creep Lousy caper loused me around for my broad (girl)
>   and my case dough (the last of my money) while I was waiting to go to
>   bat (stand trial)." -Dictionary of American underworld lingo.

Comment: Yep, it's an idiom all right.

Answer (score 1):

1) I've never heard "louse around". I think you mean "lounge around."

2) To "louse up" might mean to fill with lice; that would ruin most things. Or it may be a back formation from "lousy", now meaning generically bad but (I think) derived from that root.